# Is control location relative to visible area of form when form has scroll bar?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a VB.NET form that dynamically creates a set of controls.  If there are too many controls to view on the form, the form will show a scroll bar.  (It is an autoscroll form.)

The user can scroll down and click a button which causes the form to change dramatically.  It destroys all controls and draws new ones based on user input.

I've noticed that if the user is scrolled to the bottom of the form and click the button, when I destroy and create new controls they aren't located where I want them.  It seems to put them relative to the visible portion of the form rather than the top of the top.

Example:

```
 checkbox1.top = 50
 checkbox1.left = 15
```

If the scrollbar is all the way at the bottom, the checkbox should be placed above the visible part of the form.  Instead, it is drawn 50 pixels from the top of what I can see.

Please help.  How do I make it place the control at an absolute location, rather than being relative to the current position of the scrollbar?

Comment: One of the few good reasons to use SuspendLayout + ResumeLayout(true) methods.

Answer (score 3):

You have to compensate for the scroll position of the container control.

If a panel, then it would look like this:

```
checkbox1.Top = Panel1.AutoScrollPosition.Y + 50
```

Alternatively, you could just use a FlowLayoutPanel control, which would handle the placement of the controls for you.