# Location properties on winforms acting strange

Tags: vb.net, winforms, spacing

I have a form where I allow the user to generate multiple panels with some various contents in the panels by pressing an "add" button. Depending on what the user does in the panel, the panel grows and shrinks to fit the contents. Because of this change is size, I have created a sub that formats the panels on the form.

```
Private Sub formatPanels(frm As Form)
    Dim count As Integer = 0
    Dim startPoint As Point = New Point(12, 80)
    Dim endPoint As Point = New Point(0, 0)
    Dim maxY As Integer = 0
    For Each pnl As Control In frm.Controls
        If TypeOf pnl Is Panel Then
            ReDim Preserve _arr_Panels(count)
            _arr_Panels(count) = pnl
            count += 1
            pnl.Location = startPoint
            startPoint.Y += pnl.Size.Height + 30
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

So as you can see, we loop through every panel and the first always begins at the location (12,80) and then increments with the size of the panel and some spacing.

HERE IS THE ISSUE. This ONLY happens when i am SCROLLED DOWN the form. The panels spacing all of a sudden screws up and decides to put the first panel hundreds of pixels down the form. Is the location property based on what you're looking at? So if I were scrolled down the form location(0,0) would be the top left of the current view? There must be some weird property to location that I am not aware of.

Thanks

Comment: Looping through the `Controls` collection of a control follows the z-order, so I wouldn't be surprised if the z-order of your `Panel` controls is not what you expect.  Instead of using the very inefficient code to build a array all the time, why not just create a `List(Of Panel)` at the outset and add your `Panels` to that as you create them? That way, you can simply loop through that every time and then, amongst other advantages, z-order becomes irrelevant.

Comment: Also, why do you have a method that you're passing the form into?  You say "I have a form", which seems to suggest that this only applies to one form. In that case, the method to manipulate the `Panels` should be inside that form and it should refer to itself using `Me`. Even if you have multiple forms, you may well still be able to put that functionality into a base class.

Comment: Having said all that, your code may be completely unnecessary anyway. It's quite likely that you should be using a `TableLayoutPanel` or `FlowLayoutPanel` anyway, in which case the layout is handled automatically.

Comment: Is the Anchor property set on your panels ?

Comment: Okay I switched to using a list of panels, it works way better. However, my issue is not solved. It is still as if the 'start point' (12,18) is dependent on what I am viewing rather than the very top left point of the form. When I am scrolled down the form, I still get major spacing issues. It only happens when I am scrolled down the form. I know this to be true because I have tried with resizing the form itself. Anchor properties have not been set I tried them and they don't do anything. This isn't an issue with controls within the panel but the panels themselves.

Comment: This is a bit tricky, but I have encountered such problems before that relate to your screen itself sometimes. What you can do, is place an empty panel that can't be seen (But it is not set to invisible) and use its location to set other objects' locations. If someone tries your program on a different screen size, then everything will be messed up. It might only work on your current laptop/PC or whatever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior is not related to a panel, but to any control on a form with `AutoScroll = True` and `Anchor` including `Top`.  (Note: if `Anchor` didn't also include `Left` I had some strange positioning on the first call of the function.

The solution is [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19917225/is-control-location-relative-to-visible-area-of-form-when-form-has-scroll-bar) which is to use AutoScrollPosition.   If you change your startPoint to this it will adjust for the scroll position.

```
Dim startPoint As Point = New Point(12, Me.AutoScrollPosition.Y + 80)
```

And the documentation for [AutoScrollPosition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.scrollablecontrol.autoscrollposition(v=vs.110).aspx) states this:

> When adding controls programmatically to a form, use the AutoScrollPosition property to position the control either inside or outside of the current viewable scroll area.

Comment: This is the answer. Solved my problem.